# Getting a success with compilation error while trying to create a trigger for all my tables

Tags: plsql, oracle

I'm getting this message from logs:

> oracle.dbtools.worksheet.commands.scriptrunner.task.StatementRunnerTask.handleBinds(StatementRunnerTask.java:106)

Here is the full error report:

```
Error report -
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at line 29
24344. 00000 -  "success with compilation error"
*Cause:    A sql/plsql compilation error occurred.
*Action:   Return OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO along with the error code
```

And this is my whole script:

````
DECLARE
   v_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
   v_trigger_name VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
   FOR table_rec IN (SELECT table_name FROM tables_to_check) LOOP
   
     -- TRUNCATE TRIGGER NAME
      v_trigger_name := SUBSTR(table_rec.table_name || '_audit_trigger', 1, 30);
      v_sql :=
         'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ' || v_trigger_name || ' ' ||
         'BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ' || table_rec.table_name || ' ' ||
         'FOR EACH ROW ' ||
         'DECLARE ' ||
         '   v_operation VARCHAR2(10); ' ||
         'BEGIN ' ||
         '   IF INSERTING THEN ' ||
         '      v_operation := ''INSERT''; ' ||
         '   ELSIF UPDATING THEN ' ||
         '      v_operation := ''UPDATE''; ' ||
         '   ELSIF DELETING THEN ' ||
         '      v_operation := ''DELETE''; ' ||
         '   END IF; ' ||
         '   ' ||
         '   INSERT INTO audit_log (table_name, operation, timestamp, username) ' ||
         '   VALUES (''' || table_rec.table_name || ''', v_operation, SYSTIMESTAMP, USER); ' ||
         'END; ';
      
      -- Execute the dynamically generated SQL statement
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
   END LOOP;
END;
/```


I don't know what I should do with this
````

Comment: Instead of directly executing the dynamic sql try to get the sql using `DBMS_OUTPUT` and check what is the issue. Might be `/` at the end of the trigger is needed.

Comment: Just to comment, you should really give `timestamp` and `username` mandatory defaults using `default on null` (12c onwards) and stop setting them explicitly everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure uses table that contains certain table names, so - let's create it first.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tables_to_check
  2  AS
  3     SELECT 'TEST' table_name FROM DUAL;

Table created.
```

Your code:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_sql           VARCHAR2 (1000);
  3     v_trigger_name  VARCHAR2 (30);
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR table_rec IN (SELECT table_name FROM tables_to_check)
  6     LOOP
  7        -- TRUNCATE TRIGGER NAME
  8        v_trigger_name := SUBSTR (table_rec.table_name || '_audit_trigger', 1, 30);
  9        v_sql :=
 10              'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER '
 11           || v_trigger_name
 12           || ' '
 13           || 'BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON '
 14           || table_rec.table_name
 15           || ' '
 16           || 'FOR EACH ROW '
 17           || 'DECLARE '
 18           || '   v_operation VARCHAR2(10); '
 19           || 'BEGIN '
 20           || '   IF INSERTING THEN '
 21           || '      v_operation := ''INSERT''; '
 22           || '   ELSIF UPDATING THEN '
 23           || '      v_operation := ''UPDATE''; '
 24           || '   ELSIF DELETING THEN '
 25           || '      v_operation := ''DELETE''; '
 26           || '   END IF; '
 27           || '   '
 28           || '   INSERT INTO audit_log (table_name, operation, timestamp, username) '
 29           || '   VALUES ('''
 30           || table_rec.table_name
 31           || ''', v_operation, SYSTIMESTAMP, USER); '
 32           || 'END; ';
 33
 34        -- Execute the dynamically generated SQL statement
 35        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
 36     END LOOP;
 37  END;
 38  /
ERROR:
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at line 35



Warning: PL/SQL compilation errors.
```

Errors?

```
SQL> show err
No errors.
SQL>
```

OK, it wasn't *this* procedure, but code stored in `V_SQL`. What does it say? Instead of executing it, display it:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_sql           VARCHAR2 (1000);
<snip>
 34        -- Execute the dynamically generated SQL statement
 35        dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
 36        --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
 37     END LOOP;
 38  END;
 39  /
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_audit_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON TEST FOR EACH ROW DECLARE    v_operation VARCHAR2(10); BEGIN    IF INSERTING
THEN       v_operation := 'INSERT';    ELSIF UPDATING THEN       v_operation :=
'UPDATE';    ELSIF DELETING THEN       v_operation := 'DELETE';    END IF;
INSERT INTO audit_log (table_name, operation, timestamp, username)    VALUES
('TEST', v_operation, SYSTIMESTAMP, USER); END;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

When formatted and executed:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_audit_trigger
  2     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  3     ON TEST
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  DECLARE
  6     v_operation  VARCHAR2 (10);
  7  BEGIN
  8     IF INSERTING
  9     THEN
 10        v_operation := 'INSERT';
 11     ELSIF UPDATING
 12     THEN
 13        v_operation := 'UPDATE';
 14     ELSIF DELETING
 15     THEN
 16        v_operation := 'DELETE';
 17     END IF;
 18
 19     INSERT INTO audit_log (table_name,
 20                            operation,
 21                            timestamp,
 22                            username)
 23          VALUES ('TEST',
 24                  v_operation,
 25                  SYSTIMESTAMP,
 26                  USER);
 27  END;
 28  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER TEST_AUDIT_TRIGGER:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
15/4     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
15/16    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
SQL>
```

Whoops! Table doesn't exist! Why didn't you create it?

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE audit_log
  2  (
  3     table_name   VARCHAR2 (30),
  4     operation    VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     timestamp    TIMESTAMP,
  6     username     VARCHAR2 (20)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Now run the *original* code (this):

```
 <snip>
 34        -- Execute the dynamically generated SQL statement
 35        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
 36     END LOOP;
 37  END;
 38  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Here it is:

```
SQL> select trigger_name from user_triggers where table_name = 'TEST';

TRIGGER_NAME
------------------------------
TEST_AUDIT_TRIGGER

SQL>
```

---

So, basic debugging technique: first **verify** what you're about to execute then **execute** it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (id NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE "b" (id NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE tables_to_check (table_name) AS
SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE audit_log (
    table_name VARCHAR2(30),
    operation  VARCHAR2(10),
    timestamp  TIMESTAMP,
    username   VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Then if you run your PL/SQL block then it will fail as it tries to generate the query for table `b` but it uses an unquoted identifier and, in Oracle, unquoted identifiers will be implicitly converted to upper-case whereas the table is defined using a quoted identifier in lower-case. To fix that particular issue, you would need to enquote the table name and can do that using the `DBMS_ASSERT` package:

```sql
DECLARE
   v_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
   v_trigger_name VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
   FOR table_rec IN (SELECT table_name FROM tables_to_check) LOOP
     -- TRUNCATE TRIGGER NAME
      v_trigger_name := DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(
        SUBSTR(table_rec.table_name || '_ATRG', 1, 30),
        capitalize => FALSE
      );
      v_sql :=
         q'[CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ]' || v_trigger_name || q'[
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ]'
|| DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(table_rec.table_name, capitalize => FALSE)
|| q'[
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  v_operation VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    v_operation := 'INSERT';
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    v_operation := 'UPDATE';
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    v_operation := 'DELETE';
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO audit_log (table_name, operation, timestamp, username)
  VALUES (]'
|| DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(table_rec.table_name)
|| q'[, v_operation, SYSTIMESTAMP, USER); 
END;]';
      
      -- Execute the dynamically generated SQL statement
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/afods__k)